# Image Scalling with multiple UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionview, tvos, nsindexpath

I am building a tvos app. I have a `UITableView` which has around 25-30 sections. Each section has only one row and in each row i have only one horizontal `UICollectionView` which has only one section but many rows. In each row in `UICollectionView` i have an image view which i scale up when the `UICollectionViewCell` is selected.

I know i can  do this with `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` but my case is little more complicated. Actually i have two imageViews in `UICollectionViewCell` i am using `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` on the bigger imageView but if use it on the smaller imageView then i will look really bad. So that's why i have to use the scaling on the smaller imageView.

The issue i am facing is that when somewhere `UICollectionViewCell` indexPath are messing up, which results that when i go to some new `UICollectionViewCell` the smaller image is already scaled and i becomes bigger and bigger and some cells are really very very big because of the over scaling

Here is the image for storyboard setup

[image]

Here is my code any help will be great.

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        guard let nextIndexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath else{
            return
        }


        guard let nextFocusedCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(nextIndexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell else{
            return

        }

        if nextFocusedCell.teacherImageView != nil {
            coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
                let focusedTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(nextFocusedCell.teacherImageView.transform, 1.4, 1.4)
                nextFocusedCell.teacherImageView.transform =  focusedTransform
                },
                completion: nil
            )

        }

        guard let previousIndexPath = context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath else {
            return

        }

        guard let prevFocusedCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(previousIndexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell else{
            return

        }

        if prevFocusedCell.teacherImageView != nil {
            coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
                let focusedTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(prevFocusedCell.teacherImageView.transform, 1/1.4, 1/1.4)
                prevFocusedCell.teacherImageView.transform =  focusedTransform
                },
                completion: nil
            )

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my problem. Actually there are multiple `UICollecetionViews` in this setup in each section of the `UITableView`. So function

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator)
```

is called multiple times when i move vertically means when the i move between different rows of in the image, and in this case both cell which are at indexPaths `context.nextFocusedIndexPath` and `context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath` are not valid, only one of them is valid and other is `nil` so i can't return if one of them is `nil` i have to check both of them.

Similary when i move horizontially in one row or more precisely in one `UITableView` section then in that case

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator)`

is called once and both `context.nextFocusedIndexPath` and `context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath` are valid, so i have to change the `CGAffineTransform` on both of them.

Here is the updated code this can further be improved.

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {


        let nextIndexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath
        if let nextIP = nextIndexPath {
            let nextFocusedCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(nextIP) as? MyCollectionViewCell

            if let nextCell = nextFocusedCell {

                if nextCell.teacherImageView != nil {
                    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
                        let focusedTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(nextCell.teacherImageView.transform, 1.4, 1.4)
                        nextCell.teacherImageView.transform =  focusedTransform
                        },
                        completion: nil
                    )
                }
            }
        }


        let previousIndexPath = context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath
        if let prevIP = previousIndexPath {
            let previousFocusedCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(prevIP) as? MyCollectionViewCell

            if let previousCell = previousFocusedCell {

                if previousCell.teacherImageView != nil {
                    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
                        let focusedTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(previousCell.teacherImageView.transform, 1/1.4, 1/1.4)
                        previousCell.teacherImageView.transform =  focusedTransform
                        },
                        completion: nil
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```